# XML deserialize from stream with multiple objects

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, tcp, memorystream

I exchange some objects between two applications using the TcpClient and TcpListener classes. I use XML serialization (see code below). Basically everything works fine. The problem is that when one application sends multiple objects in a short period of time, I have multiple objects in the MemoryStream on the receiving side (Multiple root-Elements, also with XML version tag). How can I handle all objects and what would be the best way to do so? I could group the objects in a List and de/serialize the whole List but sooner or later I will face the same problem.
This looks like a common problem I think, but I did not find a solution yet.

Object to serialize:

```
public class DataModel
{
    public string Command { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    // ctor etc
}
```

Receiving side:

```
private void onRead(IAsyncResult ar)
    {    

        int nBytes = _client.GetStream().EndRead(ar);

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataModel));
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        DataModel dmo = (DataModel)serializer.Deserialize(memStream);
        buffer = new byte[1024];
        _client.GetStream().BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(onRead), null);

        // read on if more available...

    }
```

Example stream content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DataModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Command>XXX</Command>
  <Value>1.0</Value>
</DataModel><?xml version="1.0"?>
<DataModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Command>XXX</Command>
  <Value>5</Value>
</DataModel><?xml version="1.0"?>
<DataModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Command>XXX</Command>
  <Value>YYY</Value>
</DataModel>
```

I removed try/catch, debug things and everything unnecessary

Comment: Whenever you send data you need to terminate each message using one or more of the following techniques 1) ASCII : Terminate each message with a know character not used in message 2) ASCII or Binary : Add prefix to message with byte count. 3) Ascii or Binary : send fix length messages.  In your case I would terminate each DataModel element with a character like ETX (0x03) or EOT (0x04).  Then remove character before saving xml.  Process each element separately.

Answer (score 0):

First, did you agree to this pattern?  Maybe the other app has a bug and should be sending each Xml document separately.  In which cast, this isn't you problem to fix.

But, if you did agree to this, or are using a persistent connection:

Your problem is not really Xml related.  You can have the same issue with any type of content coming over an open connection.

The problem is that you're not 'framing' the incoming stream correctly.

You have read each individual XmlDocument from the stream separately, each into it's own internal Stream.  Then you can do whatever you want with is as it's now valid Xml.

You can either read byte by byte, looking for Declaration to indicate the next document or you can probably use an XmlReader, also testing for the next Declaration, otherwise, it will raise an exception.